# Skit-learn with Spacy parallelization error with RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, parallel-processing, spacy

I use Sklearn and Spacy to make a NLP machine learning model. But, I have a parallelization error when I train my model with the class `RandomizedSearchCV()`.

My class `TextProcessor` allows me to do text processing with the Spacy library.

```
class TextProcessor(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, remove_stop_word=False):
        self.remove_stop_word = remove_stop_word
        self.nlp = spacy.load('en')
        self.punctuations = string.punctuation

    def spacy_text_processing(self, sentence):
        '''
        This function allow to process the text with spacy
        '''
        final_sentence = []
        for word in self.nlp(sentence):
            if self.remove_stop_word:
                if word.is_stop:
                    continue

            if word.text not in self.punctuations:
                final_sentence.append(word.lemma_)

        return final_sentence

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        X_transformed = []
        for sentence in X:
            X_transformed.append(' '.join(self.spacy_text_processing(sentence)))
        return X_transformed

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
```

After that I use a sklearn pipeline to perform different processing on the text and finally I add a SVR model (the error comes with any type of model). But when I use the parameter `n_jobs` with a value other than 1 I get a parallelization error.

```
param_grid = {...} 

svr_model = Pipeline([('text_processing', TextProcessor()),
                    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),
                    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                    ('svr', SVR())])

random_search_svr = RandomizedSearchCV(svr_model, param_grid, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', n_jobs=-1)
random_search_svr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

This problem is very annoying because training models with classes like `GridSearchCV()` and `RandomizedSearchCV()` take a lot of time. Would there be any way to solve the problem or get around it?

The variables X_train and y_train contain the following sample values:

```
X_train = ["Morrisons book second consecutive quarter of sales growth", "Glencore to refinance its short-term debt early, shares rise", ...] #List of sentences

y_train = [0.43, 0.34, ...] #Sentiment between -1 and 1 associate to the sentence
```

The error is :

```
Exception in thread QueueFeederThread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\loky\backend\queues.py", line 150, in _feed
    obj_ = dumps(obj, reducers=reducers)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\loky\backend\reduction.py", line 243, in dumps
    dump(obj, buf, reducers=reducers, protocol=protocol)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\loky\backend\reduction.py", line 236, in dump
    _LokyPickler(file, reducers=reducers, protocol=protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py", line 284, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 437, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 856, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 882, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 856, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 887, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 856, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 882, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 816, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 843, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 771, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 771, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 856, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 882, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 816, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 840, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 771, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 856, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 882, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 856, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 882, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 786, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 524, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "stringsource", line 2, in preshed.maps.PreshMap.__reduce_cython__
TypeError: self.c_map cannot be converted to a Python object for pickling

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\loky\backend\queues.py", line 175, in _feed
    onerror(e, obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py", line 310, in _on_queue_feeder_error
    self.thread_wakeup.wakeup()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py", line 155, in wakeup
    self._writer.send_bytes(b"")
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 183, in send_bytes
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 136, in _check_closed
    raise OSError("handle is closed")
OSError: handle is closed

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_RemoteTraceback                          Traceback (most recent call last)
_RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\loky\backend\queues.py", line 150, in _feed
    obj_ = dumps(obj, reducers=reducers)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\loky\backend\reduction.py", line 243, in dumps
    dump(obj, buf, reducers=reducers, protocol=protocol)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\loky\backend\reduction.py", line 236, in dump
    _LokyPickler(file, reducers=reducers, protocol=protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py", line 284, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 437, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 856, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 882, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 856, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 887, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 856, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 882, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 816, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 843, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 771, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 771, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 856, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 882, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 816, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 840, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 771, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 856, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 882, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 856, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 882, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 786, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 524, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "stringsource", line 2, in preshed.maps.PreshMap.__reduce_cython__
TypeError: self.c_map cannot be converted to a Python object for pickling
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-8979d799633f> in <module>
     15 
     16 random_search_svr = RandomizedSearchCV(svr_grid_model, param_grid_svr,scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error',n_jobs=-1)
---> 17 random_search_svr.fit(X_train, y_train)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    720                 return results_container[0]
    721 
--> 722             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    723 
    724         results = results_container[0]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1513         evaluate_candidates(ParameterSampler(
   1514             self.param_distributions, self.n_iter,
-> 1515             random_state=self.random_state))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params)
    709                                for parameters, (train, test)
    710                                in product(candidate_params,
--> 711                                           cv.split(X, y, groups)))
    712 
    713                 all_candidate_params.extend(candidate_params)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    928 
    929             with self._backend.retrieval_context():
--> 930                 self.retrieve()
    931             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
    932             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in retrieve(self)
    831             try:
    832                 if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
--> 833                     self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
    834                 else:
    835                     self._output.extend(job.get())

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in wrap_future_result(future, timeout)
    519         AsyncResults.get from multiprocessing."""
    520         try:
--> 521             return future.result(timeout=timeout)
    522         except LokyTimeoutError:
    523             raise TimeoutError()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    423                 raise CancelledError()
    424             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 425                 return self.__get_result()
    426 
    427             self._condition.wait(timeout)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in __get_result(self)
    382     def __get_result(self):
    383         if self._exception:
--> 384             raise self._exception
    385         else:
    386             return self._result

PicklingError: Could not pickle the task to send it to the workers.
```

Version:

- Python: 3.7.1
- Spacy: 2.2.1
- Sklearn: 0.20.1

Comment: Could you provide a minimal test case? Some `X_train` and `y_train` would be helpful to recreate the error.

Comment: Your example doesn't use spaCy.

Comment: @AlexRamses I completed the post. X_train is a list containing sentences and y_train the list of corresponding sentiments.

Comment: @erip I'have update the post. Spacy is use in the class TextProcessor. In the ``transform()`` method I receive raw data and I return the processed data using Spacy.

Comment: I'm unable to recreate the error in Google Colaboratory. Perhaps you could try moving `self.nlp` outside of the class. I suspect the error come from when you're trying to pickle the spacy object.

Comment: Also, in the code you provided, you're fitting `random_search_svr` instead of `random_search`.

Comment: Ok, some how I'm able to recreate the error after restarting a new kernel. Will figure out it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the issue lies with the parallel backend of sklearn, which uses `'loky'` by default. Changing the backend to `'multiprocessing'` solves this problem. As mentioned here [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3193).

More info on sklearn parallel backend can be found [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.parallel_backend.html).

First, import this:

```
from sklearn.externals.joblib import parallel_backend
```

When running the fit, do this to overwrite the parallel backend:

```
with parallel_backend('multiprocessing'):
  random_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```